# Print PHP array results into HTML selectable list

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the following code printing out an `array`. I'd like to print this out into a selectable `list`.

```
foreach ($local as $record)
{
    print($record->friendlyName);
}
```

**Output example:**

> [checkbox] Option 1
>
> [checkbox] Option 2
>
> [checkbox] Option 3
>
> [checkbox] Option 4
>
> [checkbox] Option 5

Ideally I could take action on the selected option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. Depends, what value you want to get. Whether it's id of $record or it's friendlyName.

Its friendlyName:

```
    <?php foreach ($local as $record) { ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="<?=$record->friendlyName?>">
      <a><?=$record->friendlyName?></a>
      <br>
    <?php } ?>
```

Its ID:

```
    <?php foreach ($local as $recordId => $record) { ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="<?=$recordId?>">
      <a><?=$record->friendlyName?></a>
      <br>
    <?php } ?>
```